# Opengl is rendering the color of first pixel

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, textures, soil

I am trying to port my game engine from win/linux to mac os x and all works fine except for the textures. I use SOIL to load the textures and GLSL shaders to render and all it's done in C++.

I believe my shader is working properly:

gl_FragColor = texture2D( BSTextureUnit, textureCoordinates ) * BSTextureColor;

here is how I load the texture:

```
theTextureId = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
(
 nameChar,
 SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
 SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
 SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
 );

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, theTextureId);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

//glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
//glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

if(!theTextureId)
{
    std::cout<<"texture NOT loaded successfully: "<<name<<'\n';
}
```

What it does is it loads the texture, but instead of rendering all the pixels, it gives the hole object the color of the first pixel in the image.

So, if the texture is this one:

[image]

it will render a green block.

EDIT:
the texture coordinates:

```
dataToSet[0].texCoord.s = texLeft;
dataToSet[0].texCoord.t = texTop;
dataToSet[1].texCoord.s = texLeft;
dataToSet[1].texCoord.t = texBottom;
dataToSet[2].texCoord.s = texRight;
dataToSet[2].texCoord.t = texBottom;
dataToSet[3].texCoord.s = texRight;
dataToSet[3].texCoord.t = texTop;
```

where: GLfloat texTop = 1, texBottom = 0, texLeft = 0, texRight = 1;
I also tried with the texture width and height instead of 0 and 1, and I got the same result. On windows it renders correctly with this texture coordinates.

Comment: Seems like a uv problem to me. Try printing out the uv coordinates for every vertex.

Comment: UV coordinates == texture coordinates. BTW, in OpenGL those are usually referred to by S,T,R,Q